# Custom hidden field validation using jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a form:

```
<form id="actualForm"  action="" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="o-group">
            <input placeholder="Title"  id="name" name="title">
        </div>        
        <div class="o-group">
            <textarea id="description">Enter Description </textarea>
        </div> 
        <div class="o-group">
            <input placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name">
        </div>
</form>
```

In the above form description field is nic Text Editor field, that means value of this field will not be retrieved by id="description" and name is auto Complete field, So when I put validation rules for the above:

```
> $("#actualForm").validate({
>                rules:{
>                         title: {
>                                 required: true,
>                                 minlength: 2
>                         },
>                         description: {
>                                 required: true,
>                                 minlength: 2
>                         }
>                 },
>                 messages: {
>                         title: {
>                                 required: "Please enter a title",
>                                 minlength: "At least 2 characters"
>                         },
>                         description: {
>                                 required: "Please enter a description",
>                                 minlength: "At least 2 characters"
>                         }
>                 },
>                 submitHandler: function(form) { return false; }
>         });
```

Now when I call object.validate(); it does not validate description field and how to validate name field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**

```
function validateForm(){
// Create hidden input fields for description and name
// Assign values to them as:
$("hiddenDescription").val($(".nicEdit-main").html());
$("hiddenName").val("take value from autocomplete");
$("#actualForm").validate({
                 ignore:"", 
>                rules:{
>                         title: {
>                                 required: true,
>                                 minlength: 2
>                         },
>                         description: {
>                                 required: true,
>                                 minlength: 2
>                         }
>                 },
>                 messages: {
>                         title: {
>                                 required: "Please enter a title",
>                                 minlength: "At least 2 characters"
>                         },
>                         description: {
>                                 required: "Please enter a description",
>                                 minlength: "At least 2 characters"
>                         }
>                 },
>                 submitHandler: function(form) { return false; }
>         });
}
```

**

Validation messages will be displayed below hidden fields, place them according to your need.